# Rails Tree Structure API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I have JSON:
[JSON Link](https://pastebin.com)

Now I need to create parent child relationship.
So that I can consume data:

```
HTTP GET /:tree_id
=> Return the saved structure
HTTP GET /:tree_id/parent/:id
=> Return the list of parents
HTTP GET /:tree_id/child/:id
=> Return the list of childs
```

I have Couple gems eg. **acts_as_tree & ancestry** But all the above gems are providing me use parent.children to get the data.

But I nee to consume above API. Can you please help how i should use association and model structure to save and get the data based on above REST request.

Comment: What exactly do you mean "I need to create parent child relationship"? What is the output you are trying to create?

Comment: HTTP GET /:tree_id/parent/:id, If someone hits this url it, It will return the list of parents IDs Or HTTP GET /:tree_id/child/:id => Return the list of childs

Comment: It can be a search function to find Child/Parent nodes

Comment: What would be the problem to implement the endpoint performing a request to the datastore, getting all the parents/children and returning them?

Comment: Please do not link to external sites that host your code. If you have code that is relevant to your question then you must include it directly in your question.

Comment: I know that Its a link for Pastbin. And i believe thats completely fine.

Comment: I'm confused. If `/:tree_id/parent/:id` is supposed to return a _list_ of parents, what exacty is the `:id` param?

Comment: This is a bit too broad, unfortunately. I advise to add your attempts to make models/controllers, if possible.

Comment: I can’t visit pastebin from here so I can’t see your example. If you think it’s “completely fine” to leave out the only meaningful and relevant code that would enable me or anyone else to answer your question then I’m not sure why you’d take the time to ask one at all. SO gives you the tools you need to include it in your post; why would you go out of your way to make it harder for people to help you? What benefit do you get from using an external site that beats the drawback of people being unable to see your code and being unable to answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

How about you create a module like:

```
module Ancestry

  def self.extended(receiver)
    receiver.class_eval do 

      define_method(:children_ids) do |children_ary=[]|
        receiver[:child].each_with_object(children_ary) do |child, children_ary|
          children_ary << child[:id]
          child.extend(Ancestry).children_ids(children_ary)
        end if receiver[:child].any?
      end

      define_method(:parent_ids) do |parents_ary=[]|
        if receiver[:child].any?
          parents_ary << receiver[:id]
          receiver[:child].each_with_object(parents_ary) do |child, parents_ary|
            child.extend(Ancestry).parent_ids(parents_ary)
          end
        end
      end

      define_method(:node) do |node_id|
        return receiver if receiver[:id] == node_id
        receiver[:child].each do |child|
          child.extend(Ancestry).node(node_id).tap do |x| 
            return x unless x.blank?
          end
        end if receiver[:child]
        {}.extend(Ancestry)
      end

      define_method(:child) do 
        receiver[:child] || []
      end

    end
  end

end
```

Then extend your `hash` like this:

```
data = {
  "id": 1,
  "child": [
    {
      "id": 1847,
      "child": [
        {
          "id": 8078,
          "child": []
        },
        {
          "id": 3380,
          "child": [
            {
              "id": 561,
              "child": []
            },
            {
              "id": 706,
              "child": []
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}.with_indifferent_access.extend(Ancestry)
```

Now you can do:

```
data.children_ids
 => [1847, 8078, 3380, 561, 706]
data.parent_ids
 => [1, 1847, 3380]
data.node(1847).node(3380).child
 => [{"id"=>561, "child"=>[]}, {"id"=>706, "child"=>[]}]
data.node(9999).node(3380).child
 => []
data.node(1847).node(9999).child
 => []
data.node(1847).node(3380).node(561).child
 => []
```

Comment: Thanks for this. But Can you please tell me if someone hitting /:tree_id/child/:id, How it works

Comment: I don't know what the `:tree_id` and `:id` are for in `/:tree_id/child/:id`. If someone visits `/4/child/3`, what do expect they will receive?

Comment: /1847/child/3380 => "child": [
            {
              "id": 561,
              "child": []
            },
            {
              "id": 706,
              "child": []
            }
          ]

Comment: Thanks for helping till now, an upvote from side.

Comment: Oooooooh. That's something entirely (or at least somewhat) different. That's why I originally asked you what output you were looking for. You should really update your question so it is clearer. Anyway, I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, God bless you :)

Comment: Glad it helped. Please feel free to accept the answer to help future searchers.

Comment: please help me if possible to find the value for this data.node(561).parent_nodes. =>>[3380, 1847, 1]